# What is the actual way to use socket io to serve many users simultaneously .?

Tags: node.js, webserver, express, websocket, socket.io

I want to have a real-time connection between many group of users and i am new to server side scripting.........I want to send certain messages(data) to certain users, now my question is how to do it either to have a same socket for all users or different sockets connection for different users or for different task ..? 

Currently I am just using a single socket and serving users this way..This is not the actual app its just a prototype of what I will be doing:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(http_port);

var allUsers=[];
var num=1;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
var user = 'user#'+num++;
allUsers[user] = socket;
socket.on('message',function(data){
    if(data.to)
        allUsers[data.to].emit("message",{msg:data.msg,by:data.by});
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
    socket.emit('message',{to:'user#1',from:'talha',msg:'hello'});
```

Maybe, I am on a wrong approach, becuase later on I will be quering to database sending those results to specific clients, how do i manage that.
Please provide some code details along with your anwers .. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only have one listening socket. On each connection (as it can be seen from `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){..`) , your `function(socket){....}` is called and the socket in that function is identical to each connection/user. The function callbacks on `"connection"` event are sepearate and one for each user.

**EDIT:**
For user seperating users you can do the following:

```
var users = [];
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
   socket.on("message", function(data){
        // Handle if it is a valid user, make some authentication and have a username..
        users[username] = socket;
        // on another message, if you want to send message  
        users["myuser"].send(...)
   }

});
```

Comment: Ok i got you, and what about selecting some specific user to send a message.